# Eclipse dont show to ADT and SDK

Tags: android, adt

i am confused about eclipse problems. I created project in android yesterday and today morning i opened to eclipse. but i saw that there is not option for creating new Android project. also i checked Windows - > preference -> Android , **Android option is also not available here**
and also Android SDK option is not in eclipse.
I import a android project and see a Red color error on it.

i have installed both ADT and SDK by

```
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
```

please help me

Comment: how can i reconfigure

Comment: if you able to download quick means download adt-bundle-for-windows and use it.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possibilities for this query:

1) First of all please check whether you have installed it correctly:

Help --> Install New Software then

add this link adt - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

and [read this too](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)

2) try Window > Customize perspective > Command Groups Availability tab. Check the "Android SDK and AVD Manager" option and hit the OK button.

If "Android SDK and AVD Manager" hasn't shown up, I think there may be some kind of file miss match in the eclipse.

3) If so, It would be better to start fresh:
[You can find the step by step guidance here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html#Installing)